# Unable to access value from database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am facing such strange problem. Please have a look over the code

```
today_date = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

patient_id = session[:patient_id]

query = QueryContainedModel.find(:first, :conditions => ["query_type = ?", 'appointment_reminder'])
```

This above query generates  query_value in below form ie query_value

```
query_value = "SELECT PATIENT.NAME AS 'first_name' FROM PATIENT, REMINDER WHERE PATIENT.ID = '#{session[:patient_id]}' 
AND REMINDER.PATIENT_ID = '#{session[:patient_id]}' AND REMINDER.DATE >= '#{today_date}'"
```

But I am unable to fetch values in below code

```
@value = ModelName.find_by_sql "#{query_value}"
@value.each do |value|
  puts value.
end
```

Comment: You should never interpolate those into the queries, you're open to injection attacks!  What is `QueryContainedModel`  and `ModelName` ?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing `query = QueryContainedModel.find(:first, :conditions => ["query_type = ?", 'appointment_reminder'])` works, why are you switching to SQL in the next bit of code?  You can easily continue to build off `query` itself - I'm assuming your `query` works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is you are trying to access a session value inside a model, But sessions are not visible to models, but only to views, helpers and controllers.

Try passing patient_id as a parameter

For example, in your controller

```
query = QueryContainedModel.find(:first, :conditions => ["query_type = ? and patient_id = ?", 'appointment_reminder', session[:patient_id]]
```

Comment: That's also a good point; I fixed a mistake in your code above.